# Rows selection based on Column Values

Tags: oracle

I have a problem where for a single value there can be maximum of two rows. I have to select only one row based on the column value.Below example can show my data and what I am trying to achieve.

```
Table Item with the following information
```

```
Item   Dist_Building     Country_Building
I123   B123               B245   
I980   B980               B345
I780   B780               B445
```

```
Table item_info with the following columns
```

```
Item_number Building_Nbr Building_Area  Value
I123         B123        District        10
I123         B245        Country         20
I980         B980        District        50
I780         B445        Country         20
```

Select the items from the Item table and check for the corresponding Building information present in Item_info table. If for a certain item, values are present at District and Country level then select the District level VALUE else select the Country Level VALUE(i.e. row with district area will take the priority over the Country )

```
Item_number Value
I123         10
I980         50
I780         20
```

Answer (score 0):

are the `Dist_Building`, `Country_Building`, and `Building_Nbr` important here? It looks like theyre not, in which case if you create a new table from the `item_info` table like so...

```
select 
  item_number
  , building_nbr
  , sum(case when building_area = 'District' then value end) as District_Val
  , sum(case when building_area = 'Country' then value end) as Country_Val
  , coalesce(District_Val, Country_Val) as Value 
into new_item_info
from item_info
group by 
  1,2
```

you should be able to just left join it to the `item` table. 
(im not that familiar with Oracle SQL, so you may have to break the above code in to two steps)

Comment: Oracle doesn't let you use a column alias in the same level of query as it was defined, so your `coalesce` will get an 'invalid identifier'. You would need to use a subquery. (I think that's a SQL restriction so true of all databases, but not 100% sure). You can't use column position numbers in the `group by` clause either; and `into` isn't right here. This is quite a long way from being usable for an Oracle-tagged question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by simply using sub-queries and the NVL function:

```
SELECT Item
     , NVL((SELECT VALUE FROM item_info ii 
             WHERE ii.item_number = i.item
               AND ii.Building_Nbr = i.Dist_Building)
          ,(SELECT VALUE FROM item_info ii 
             WHERE ii.item_number = i.item
               AND ii.Building_Nbr = i.Country_Building)) VALUE
  FROM Item i
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a join to either building, and then keep the one with the 'higher' area value (which works here as 'District' sorts after 'Country'):

```
select i.item,
  max(ii.value) keep (dense_rank last order by ii.building_area) as value 
from item i
join item_info ii on ii.item_number = i.item
and (
  (ii.building_nbr = i.dist_building and ii.building_area = 'District')
  or (ii.building_nbr = i.country_building and ii.building_area = 'Country')
)
group by i.item;

ITEM      VALUE
---- ----------
I123         10
I780         20
I980         50
```

You could make that more explicit with a case expression in the order-by clause if you don't want to rely on that sort order.

You could also do two outer joins and use `coalesce` to pick the one you want:

```
select i.item,
  coalesce(iid.value, iic.value) as value
from item i
left join item_info iid on iid.item_number = i.item
and iid.building_nbr = i.dist_building
and iid.building_area = 'District'
left join item_info iic on iic.item_number = i.item
and iic.building_nbr = i.country_building
and iic.building_area = 'Country';

ITEM      VALUE
---- ----------
I123         10
I780         20
I980         50
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1362232f03fbf177c1292b6233192faf)

Comment: Hi how are you suggesting to use a CASE statement in order by clause?

Comment: @sqlpractice - I was referring to the order-by clause within the `keep`; I didn't mean an overall order-by for the whole statement. So something like `max(ii.value) keep (dense_rank last order by case ii.building_area when 'Country' then 1 when 'District' then 2 end) as value`. That is more explicit and flexible, but possibly overkill in this query.